# Статический метод класса

Tags: c++

Для чего может понадобиться обьёвлять метод класса, используя спецификатор static? Переменные в этом методе так же будут static? Что будет происходить при создании нескольких экземпляров класса? Как в памяти всё это дело будет храниться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статический метод может работать со статическими переменными класса и с объектами класса.
Он может выполнять какие-то действия общие для всех объектов данного класса или для указываемой группы объектов, изменение общих параметров, что-то вроде сборки мусора и т.д.

- Переменные внутри метода не обязательно будут static.
- Создание и уничтожение экземпляров класса никак не затронет статический метод, его можно вызывать независимо от существования объектов класса. Это аналог обычной функции, только имя у неё необычное и область видимости.
- Существование статического метода никак не отражается на том, как будет храниться объект класса.

Comment: То есть именно статический метод подходит для CallBack функций!? Предположим требуется в каждом экземпляре запускать таймеры (SetTimer) с разными параметрами, то для всех экземпляров будет использоваться одна общая статическая функция (метод) CallBack !? Если да, то как привязать другие методы класса к этому CallBack`у !?

Comment: @rejie

- Статические методы действительно подходят для создания `callback'ов`. Другое дело, что эти же самые `callback'и` вполне можно реализовывать, используя лямбда-функции и функции классов *(см. `boost::lambda`, `boost::bind`).*

- Для того, чтобы использовать в `static callback'e` параметры или что-нибудь в таком духе, вы вполне можете, например, передавать эти параметры или указатели на объекты через аргументы статического метода.

Comment: А как из static callback обратиться к не статическим экземплярам класса?!

Answer (score 2):

- Описание на **msdn** [модификатора **`static`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/98f28cdx.aspx)
- [Здесь более подробно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s1sb61xd.aspx) про **`static`** в **C++**

Comment: В примерах на тему static чаще всего - подсчет созданных экземпляров класса.

Answer (score 2):

Объявление метода как static позволяет возможность блокировать вызовы для RValue-объекта даже при компиляции в стандарте c++98.

```
//C++11
class A{
public:
void f()const&;
void f()const&&=delete;
void g()&;
};
{ A a;
  a.f(); //ok
  A().f(); //bad
  a.g(); //ok
  A().g(); //bad
  }

//C++98
class A{
public:
static void f(A const * );
static void g(A & );
};
{ A a;
  A::f(&a); //ok
  A::f(&A()); //bad
  A::g(a); //ok
  A::g(A()); //bad
  }
```